# how to count number of associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following models

```
:order has_many :dishes
:dish has_and_belongs_to_many :items
```

I have a collection @orders, how I count the :item?

e.g. I have 3 items, chicken, beef and pork. And two dishes, first has both chicken and beef, second has chicken, beef and pork. Two orders, the first order contains the dish #1 and the second order has both dishes. I would like to know there are 3 for beef, 3 for chicken and 1 for pork.

How can I achieve this in rails?

Comment: Currently what I am doing is merging all the associated items into an array, and then find the occurrence of each unique items. Looking for better methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question, I don't know of any particularly nice ways of doing this, hopefully someone will post one, but in the meantime you can find the counts by iterating through unique elements and counting the occurrences:

```
items = <gather all the items into one array>
items.uniq.each do |item|
  puts item.name
  puts items.count(item)
end
```

To gather all of the child items into an array it would be best if you had a `:has_many through` relationship so you can directly get an orders items, skipping the dishes:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dishes
  has_many :items, through => :dishes
end

items = @orders.map(&:items).flatten
```

Comment: thanks, this is what I ended up doing with. Gather all the elements first and then find out the count of unique items.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't this work?

```
@beef_orders = @orders.dishes.items.where(:ingredients => "beef").count
```

Comment: thanks for reply. But the problem is that there are many items, not only 3. I wanna something like { "beef" => 3, "chicken" => 3, "pork" => 1, ... }. Currently what I am doing is merging all the associated items into an array, and then find the occurrence of each unique items. Looking for better methods.